# <video> html5 в safari

Tags: html5, видео, safari

Необходимо вывести видео с прозрачным фоном (с альфа-каналом кому как удобно). Использую формат WebM для основной тройки браузеров, но для сафари необходимо другой формат. Нашел, что в этом случае нужно использовать формат .mov. конвертнул с сохранением отсутствия фона, но в таком случае видео вообще нигде не видно (если проверять без `<source src="video/AUTO_BLICK.vebm" type="video/webm">`), конвертнул с фоном видно везде кроме safari. Подскажите может есть еще какой-то универсальный формат или с какими параметрами нужно конвертировать.
p.s. код думаю не особо поможет, но может в нем что-то не так.

```
<div class="block-car">
    <a href="#main-gift">
        <div class="car">
            <video width="300" height="150" autoplay loop muted>
                <source src="video/AUTO_BLICK.mov" type="video/mov">
                <source src="video/AUTO_BLICK.vebm" type="video/webm">
            </video>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сафари поддерживает только `H.264`:

```
<video width="560" controls>
  <source src="videos/example.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: а как же формат mov - Apple QuickTime Movie. Почему они свой формат не хотят поддерживать или это не их они забили? может кто-то подсказать по этому вопросу?